# Logcat no connected devices - even when devices are being shown in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

The message no connected devices is shown in logcat, even when devices are being shown in Android Studio.
The command adb logcat works on powershell.
The problem occurs on all my coworkers' machines (same setup).

[image: Logcat no connected devices]
[image]

S.O.: Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise 10.0.22000 N/A - 22000

IDE:

- Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 - Build
  #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023
- Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

We have already tried:

- Restart android studio;
- Restart PC;
- Invalidate cache and restart;
- Adb kill-server and restart again;
- Remove physical devices and plug in again;
- Reinstall Android Studio
- Clean

  ```
   C:\Users\username\.android 

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Google
  ```

There is something we should try? Could the problem be related to Windows Defender?

Answer (score 0):

For fix it updating Android Studio, And installing the latest SDK Platform

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).